# Django Create a user using only Email and set as inactive

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my app I have 3 kind of users with different permissions. HR, Employees and candidate.

I would like to be able to create a User employee providing only its email ans set it as inactive And when the employee sign in into the app he setup a his first name, last name and a password and become Active on the app

I am starting in django and have really no idea how to do it;

I started the authentication process using the documentation and I get to :

views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import HRForm, CandidateForm, EmployeeForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from .models import MyUser

def registerEmployee(request):
    registered  = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        Employee_form = EmployeeForm(data=request.POST)

        if Employee_form.is_valid():
            user = Employee_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.is_employee = True
            user.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print("Error!")
    else:
        Employee_form = EmployeeForm()
    return render(request,'Employee_registration_form.html',
                            {'Employee_form':Employee_form,
                             'registered':registered})
```

Could you please help me or give me direction to dive in ? 
Thx you ;)

Comment: can look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 0):

For activating/deactivating a user you could use:

```
user.is_active = False/True
```

For creating the user I recommend the following article:

https://medium.com/@ramykhuffash/django-authentication-with-just-an-email-and-password-no-username-required-33e47976b517